# Mongo query works in mongo shell but not in a bash mongo --eval?

Tags: mongodb

Here is an example query:

`db.readings.find( {"_id.s" : ISODate("2012-11-01T00:05:00Z") } ).count()`

Query works in the mongo shell. However, in a bash script or directly in the Ubuntu shell

`mongo fivemin --eval "printjson(db.readings.find( {"_id.s" : ISODate("2012-11-01T00:05:00Z") } ).count())"`

returns a `SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell eval):1`

I can't seem to find a problem with the query. I reverted to `{ "_id" : {"s" : ...} }`, and it still gives the same problem. `find().count()` works however.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue in bash shell.

This will fail because of double quotes:

```
mongo fivemin --eval "printjson(db.readings.find( {"_id.s" : ISODate("2012-11-01T00:05:00Z") } ).count())"
```

But using the eval string in single quote it works:

```
mongo fivemin --eval 'printjson(db.readings.find( {"_id.s" : ISODate("2012-11-01T00:05:00Z") } ).count())'
```

And if you use a $ sign like $regex you need to escape it:

```
mongo fivemin --eval 'printjson(db.readings.find( {"_id.s" : {"\$regex":"2012-11-01T*"} } ).count())'
```

Answer (score 1):

use single quotes into double,

e.g.:

```
mongo fivemin --eval "printjson(db.readings.find( {'_id.s' : ISODate('2012-11-01T00:05:00Z') } ).count())"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sat and thought about it. It seems to be a problem with bash exiting out on the " (should have noticed immediately!). Instead I used ' (or I guess you can use /" for JSON) so the query looks like:

`printjson(db.readings.find({'_id.s' : ISODate('2013-01-01T00:05:00Z') }).count())"`

Answer (score 0):

There is also another possible issue using `--eval` with [bash double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes-1), if the query contains mongo operators i.e. `$ne`, `$gt` etc, since operators start with `$`.

double quotes:

```
$ echo " '$ne': null "
$ => '': null
```

single quotes:

```
$ echo ' "$ne": null '
$ => "$ne": null
```

Bash tries to replace these operators with variables.

```
$ ne = 'test'
$ echo " '$ne': null "
$ => 'test': null
```

So, I always recommend to use `--eval` with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to build the mongo command in a var. Then use `eval` command to execute the mongo command:

```
mongo_update_query="db.collectionName.update({ name:\""${some_name}"\", \
{ \$addToSet: { nick_names : { \$each : [ ${name_array} ] }}});"

mongo_cmd_str=$(echo "mongo --host ${mongo_host} --port ${mongo_port} ${mongo_database} --eval '${mongo_update_query}'")

# the actual call to mongo query
eval ${mongo_cmd_str}
```