# Reference Error when inserting a string with eval into mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker

I would like to insert data into my mongodb from the command line. The mongodb is running in a docker container.

I want to do the following steps:

- Enter docker container
- Insert data into mongodb
- Exit container

The command that I am using is the following:

```
docker exec -i <id-of-mongo-container> sh -c "mongo --eval 'db.rules.insert({ description: "test123"})'"
```

But this throws the following exception:

```
[js] uncaught exception: ReferenceError: test123 is not defined
```

I think it is an issue with the quote mark mix, but I am not able to figure out how to get it right. Does someone have an idea on how to fix this?

**Research**

Something I found from research is that if you swap the string "test123" with a number e.g. 2. Than the command does work.

Therefore, the following command does work.

```
docker exec -i <id-of-mongo-container> sh -c 'mongo admin --eval "db.rules.insert({ description: 2})"'
```

It also seems to related to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435838/mongo-query-works-in-mongo-shell-but-not-in-a-bash-mongo-eval), but it is different because there is an extra set of qoutes from the `docker exec`.

Cheers!

Comment: Did you try to use escape quotes

sh -c "mongo --eval 'db.rules.insert({ description: \"test123\"})'"

Comment: @GKS Thank you so much, this pointed me in the right direction! Since I have to run it in an npm script I have to do some crazy escape character magic but it works. This is the tricky part of the npm script, ` 'db.rules.insert({ description: \\\"test123\\\", date: new Date()})'\"`. Thanks again!